# How to install OpenJUMP?

Tags: package-management

I'm trying to install [OpenJUMP](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jump-pilot/index.php?title=Installation) in Ubuntu 12.04. They mentioned that it can be installed and run on Linux:

> From the bin directory, run the starter for your operating system
>
> **Linux**
>
> ```
> oj_linux.sh
> ```

But for the life of me I can't find the *bin* directory in the source. Does anybody know how to install this?

I don't think it's in any one of the repos either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find the `Bin` directory you have to download the [OpenJUMP-Portable-1.5.2-r2930-CORE.zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jump-pilot/files/OpenJUMP/1.5.2/OpenJUMP-Portable-1.5.2-r2930-CORE.zip/download) and then extract it, then you will find the `Bin` directory inside the extracted directory.